# My hat hides my face?

Tags: support, profile-picture, winter-bash-2013

My hat shows over my avatar so that I can't see my head on Stack Overflow and all other accounts. How can I see my head on my favorite avatar?

Comment: Use a different hat.

Comment: One way is to simply adjust your profile picture byu uploading new image.

Answer (score 22):

As the [Winter Bash blog post][1] says:

> Hat position is adjustable on your face: You remember how crushed you
> were after finally earning a mustache “hat,” only to discover that on
> your avatar, it was basically an extremely dapper unibrow? NEVER
> AGAIN.
>
> You can finally reposition hats in the box until Don Draper’s suit
> fits as well it fits him. (I know, I know… “it’s not a suit; it’s a
> carousel.” Give it a rest, Don. Not everything is a carousel.)

1. Go into your profile
2. Click on your avatar icon
3. Drag your hat around to make it fit as well as you can
   [1]: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/?cb=1

Comment: It is too big. Is there any resizing options?

Comment: Nope, at least not yet. Just the ability to reposition it.

Comment: Now to make a feature request to be able to tilt my hat at a jaunty angle.

Comment: @Alconja that way madness lies.

Answer (score 1):

You won't, unfortunately, be able to make every avatar work wit certain hats. What you *can* try is making a 128x128 crop of your avatar (exactly 128x128) with a better positioned head. At 128x128, what you see is what you get.

You've got this:

[image: See, this is just huge.]

But you really want something like this:

[image: Now, that's better.]

Then you can play around with re-sizing the original a bit in order to get more in. It's pretty simple, just create a 128x128 image and *don't* preserve aspect ratio when you paste your original into it - you'll have to move it around to get it to fit in the new thumb the way you want (I used Paint.Net).

You can also re-size the original to shrink it down some prior, to fit more into the new thumb, but you probably want to maintain the aspect ratio of it during that process.

Unfortunately, at least this year, you'll have to manually tweak around certain hats that you *really* like, but just don't fit your avatar quite correctly. Next year? Who knows what that nimble [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) guy will come up with for more advanced mad-hattering.

Comment: Wow that is impossible because now my avatar is a famous step of my favorite dancer if I crop this how can I see this step? I don't want Michel Jackson's head only I need all his step.

Comment: @Bizzon This was just the best compromise I could think of, we wouldn't be able to handle this sort of case outside of resizing the hat itself. That's .. not going to be possible _this_ year, but we can look at it next year.

Comment: @Bizzon, I cannot really see that step in your avatar anyway. Maybe if I'd go into your profile, but not when shown next to a post.