# Position of my hat appears to change after I wear the hat

Tags: support, bug, design, winter-bash, profile-picture

The position of my hat appears to change after I wear the hat.

From picture 1 and 2, the sword is clearly aligned with the letter N.

However, after wearing the hat, the position of the sword is evidently placed before the letter N, as seen in picture 3.

**Picture 1**

[image]

**Picture 2**

[image]

**Picture 3 (profile page)**

[image]

This is likely due to my profile picture being shrunk to fit when displayed on the profile page.

Comment: Try avatar having 1:1 ratio, e.g. 800x800 pixels, i.e. same width and height. This way, the placement of the hat might be kept when the avatar size change.

Comment: Duplicates:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189458/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212287/282094

Answer (score 3):

#### Not an answer but rather an explanation of why this occurs.

On your profile page, the original large-sized image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv5jh.png?s=328&g=1) is linked. Hence, when it is displayed on your profile page (as seen in Picture 3 in your question), your profile picture appears to have shrinked in width.

[image]

However, in most other places, a thumbnail (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv5jh.png?s=128&g=1) of your profile image is displayed. This makes your profile picture cropped at its sides.

[image]

---

### This could be resolved by the SE developers by adding `object-fit` to the `<img>` tag on the profile page, i.e.,

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv5jh.png?s=328&amp;g=1" alt="" width="164" height="164" class="bar-sm avatar-user"
style="object-fit: cover;">

^^ this part is added
```

When `style="object-fit: cover;"` is added, the result is as follows:

[image]

For comparison, this is how your profile picture currently displays:

[image]